# Set virtual console keymap on Live(CD|USB)?

Tags: keyboard-layout, virtual-console, dvorak

How can I change the keymap of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd>to<kbd>F6</kbd>) virtual consoles on the LiveUSB/CD image?

I've tried picking my layout (US Dvorak) from the F3 menu when it first starts to boot, but that only sets the GUI Keymap and not the virtual console keymap. This is especially frustrating because of a bug in the Driver for my Video card (Neauvou) that will completely freeze the system if I do too much (seems to be related to fast cursor movement; for example, holding down backspace or arrow key in gnome-terminal). This makes me want to use the virtual consoles, but then they are the wrong layout and therefore hard to type on.

Comment: You may want to change the title of your post to "How to change the keymap of the virtual console/TTY" and leave out the part about live, as almost any method that applies to the live CD/USB will apply to an installed system and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147128/change-default-tty-shortcut/176991#176991). In short, you can remap the keys using the `loadkeys` command. For example:

```
sudo su -
echo control keycode 2 = Console_1 | loadkeys -
```

will add a binding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>1</kbd> such that it now switches to the first tty. However, it will not affect the keybindings under X!