# How to clear all global keyboard shortcuts without "SUPER"?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Is there a quick and easy way that deletes ALL global keyboard shortcuts not involving the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key?

I am asking because in my opinion, the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key is the *SYSTEM* key. If it is not involved, no system shortcut should be triggered. That is also to avoid conflicts with application-dependent shortcuts, which are often overridden by many of Ubuntu's default system-wide shortcuts. So many in fact, that I don't want to do it manually through the keyboard system manager. In addition, I cannot even find some shortcuts in that manager. E.g. in a game I am using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and nothing happens in the game, even though the shortcut manager does not list this combination.

Is there a way to quickly list/erase *ALL* shortcuts matching some condition, possibly through the command line?

This has been causing me quite a headache already. Not to forget the fact that accidentally pressing some key combinations can have severe (or just very annoying) consequences.

Comment: See this it may help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/510405/is-there-an-application-to-identify-the-configuration-driving-a-system-global-ke/576344#576344 . Looking for a kind of desktop with Game Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Most Unity desktop shortcuts are Compiz ones:

1. Install `ccsm`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Launch `ccsm`
3. Preferences → Export
4. Do you want to skip default option values while exporting your profile? **NO**
5. Copy exported file to leave a backup then open it with Gedit.
6. All Compiz shortcuts are there. Modify what you want then Import it back again.

Sometimes, it's hard know what the shortcut do. You can use GUI, go to the plugin, check their shortcuts tab, see if there any hints.

Other shortcuts:

1. Install dconf editor

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Launch it. then follow paths:

   ```
   /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/
   /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/
   ```