# How Can I Change X's TTY

Tags: xorg, tty

How can I change X's tty from Ctrl-Alt-F7 to another F Key? I have only 4 ttys so I want X on the fifth.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/147128/change-default-tty-shortcut

Comment: No, I don't want to change the shortcut for all tty's, just x's

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04.04, the xorg tty changes from tty1 to tty7 when I replace the display manager gdm3 by lightdm. To replace the display manager, I run

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Likewise, the xorg tty changes from tty7 to tty1 when I replace lightdm by gdm3.

Yet another approach involves editing `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`. In `xserverrc`, replace the line

```
exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@"
```

with

```
exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@" vt$XDG_VTNR
```

where $XDG_VTNR specifies the number of your tty.